# why does addition function not work properly

Tags: python

I am trying to make a game of blackjack, but the addition function seems to not work as I want it and I don't know why. the total is sometimes a value bigger than it should be.

```
import random

cards = ["ace", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10] user_hand = []
dealer_hand = [] hit_stand = "h" bust = False

def card_addition(hand, total):
    # return sum(hand)
    for n in hand:
        if n == "ace" and total <= 10:
            total += 11
        elif n == "ace" and total >= 11:
            total += 1
        else:
            total += n
    for n in hand:
        if n == "ace" and total > 21:
            total -= 10
    return total
        
for card in range(2):
    user_hand.append(random.choice(cards))

for card in range(1):
    dealer_hand.append(random.choice(cards))
    dealer_hand.append("hidden")

def hit(hand):
    hand.append(random.choice(cards))

user_total = 0

print (f"Your hand is {user_hand}") print (f"Dealer's hand is
{dealer_hand}")  

while user_total < 21 and hit_stand == "h":
    hit_stand = input("Hit or stand ? (h/s)")
    if hit_stand == "h":
        hit(user_hand)
        user_total = card_addition(user_hand, user_total)
        print(f"Your hand is {user_hand} and your total is {user_total}.")
    elif hit == "s":
        print("STAND !") if user_total > 21:
    bust = True
    

dealer_hand.remove("hidden") dealer_hand.append(random.choice(cards))
dealer_total = 0 dealer_total = card_addition(dealer_hand,
dealer_total)


while dealer_total < 16 and bust == False:
    hit(dealer_hand)
    dealer_total = card_addition(dealer_hand, dealer_total) print(f"Dealer hand is {dealer_hand} and the total is
{dealer_total}.")

if user_total > dealer_total and bust == False:
    print("You win !") elif dealer_total > user_total and bust == False:
    print("Dealer wins !") elif dealer_total == user_total and bust == False:
    print("Draw !")

if bust == True:
    print("BUST !")
```

output >>

```
Your hand is ['ace', 2]
Dealer's hand is [9, 'hidden']
Hit or stand ? (h/s)h
Your hand is ['ace', 2, 10] and your total is 13. 
Hit or stand ? (h/s)h
Your hand is ['ace', 2, 10, 8] and your total is 24. 
Dealer hand is [9, 8] and the total is 17. 
BUST !
```

Comment: I think the issue is that you pass the full hand in each time, but also the `user_total`.  Just do `user_total = card_addition(user_hand, 0)` Running `print(card_addition(['ace', 2, 10, 8], 0))` produces `21` just like you would expect. No idea why your previous hand's `user_total` would need to be added to that. Ultimately, just remove that parameters from your function and always sum up the full hand since the full hand is what you are working with each iteration.

Comment: Since you already have the total, when you deal a new card you should just add that card to the total, rather than adding up the whole hand each time.

Comment: Precisely when should the value of the ace be determined? Should the result be different if you add the values of `A, 2, 10` versus `2, 10, A`?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting `user_total` and `dealer_total` did it for me. Just call the functions inside the `print()`.

```py
if hit_stand == "h":
         hit(user_hand)
         print(f"Your hand is {user_hand} and your total is {card_addition(user_hand, user_total)}.")
```